# dynamic data when printed on the console is shown differently when compared with the static data when printed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-parsing

I am returning a String with comma separated values from spring controller to angular controller as shown below.

```
app.controller('myListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

//get data dynamically , logic..
$scope.myList = response;
console.log("$scope.myList  " + $scope.myList); // "one,two","three","four","five,eight,nine"

//here i want to print as one,two,three,four,five,eight,nine 

//convert string to array with comma separated values
var array_list = JSON.parse($scope.myList);
   console.log("array_list :: " + array_list);
}]);
```

The above code is throwing the error

```
angular.min.js?dummy=0.6014859345541128:119 SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 15
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

The same code , when replaced with static code, it is working as expected.
example:

```
   $scope.myList = ["one,two","three","four","five,eight,nine"];

   console.log("$scope.myList static content:: " +   $scope.myList); //one,two,three,four,five,eight,nine
```

Any inputs on the above?

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse expects a string as input that is valid JSON and returns a JavaScript Object.

JSON.stringify expects a JavaScript Object as input and returns a string.

From your example it looks like you're passing $scope.myList (a JavaScript array) into JSON.parse expecting a string result.  If $scope.myList is a JavaScript object use .stringify

If the result you're looking for is one,two,three,four,five,eight,nine then you should use Array.join method.  EX//  $scope.myList.join()

Comment: When used JSON.stringify($scope.myList) result is "\"one,two\",\"three\",\"four\",...
But i want the result as one,two,three,four,five,eight,nine @thastark

Comment: In that case you should use $scope.myList.join() ... no need to use the JSON helpers ...

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your JSON.stringify result, your response string must be this value:

```
'"one,two","three","four","five,eight,nine"'
```

If it is you can use a simple regex to get the result you want:

```
var result = $scope.myList.replace(/"/g, ""); //"one,two,three,four,five,eight,nine"
```

If this doesn't work please share the exact value of your $scope.myList